# JS expected value not met

Tags: javascript, function

So I am working on this project, and my goal is to create a snowman using java script. I've run this code multiple times and I have appeared to fix all errors but one, which is preventing me from executing the full script and ensuring it 100% validates.

I am using zybooks to learn java as an elective at my high school. And I cannot get a hold of my instructor for some guidance. When I submit the code, everything (so far) validates until a certain point.

This is my error message:

```
//incorrect //
Context lineTo() called with proper x value
Your value
46
Expected value
54
Test aborted.
```

I don't really know where to change this value. I played around with the code in `drawSingleFlake` function, but I am not getting anywhere. The truth of the matter is, I don't know where to begin changing this value.

This is my code so far:

```
const flakeSize = 8;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
   
   drawGround(canvas);
   drawSnowText(canvas);
   drawSnowman(canvas);  
   drawSnowflakes(canvas);   
});

function drawGround(canvas) {
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

   // background 
   context.fillStyle = "lightgray";
   context.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

   // ground
   context.fillStyle = "brown";
   context.fillRect(0, canvas.height - 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawSnowflakes(canvas) {   
   for (var c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
      drawSingleFlake(canvas, x, y);
   }
}

// Complete the functions below

function drawSnowText(canvas) {
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.font = '80px Verdana';
   ctx.textAlign="center";
  
   ctx.textBaseline = "top";
   ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillText("SNOW",canvas.width/2, 10);
}

function drawSnowman(canvas) { 
if (canvas.getContext) {
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150,200,50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.fillStroke = 'white';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

ctx.fill();
}
if (canvas.getContext) {
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150,120,40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

ctx.fill();
}
if (canvas.getContext) {
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150,60,25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;

ctx.fill();
}
}


// This is where I believe the error is coming from //

function drawSingleFlake(canvas, x, y) {
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
   ctx.moveTo(x,y);

   ctx.lineTo(x-flakeSize/2,y+flakeSize/2);
ctx.lineTo(x,y+(flakeSize/2));
   ctx.lineTo(x+flakeSize/2,y+flakeSize/2);
}
```

If anyone can offer any advice or help, I would greatly appreciate it. Though I appreciate anyone who can give me a solid answer, I also much rather prefer a pointer in the right direction. This class is important to me, and I want to complete this project as independently as possible.

Comment: Is this actually a Java question? It seems not to be, but you do mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem; I played some more with the `drawSingleSnowflake` function, and I ended up rewriting the entire function as follows, where some lines were reordered and `/2` was taken off of the second `ctx.lineTo()` line.

```
function drawSingleFlake(canvas, x, y) {
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.moveTo(x,y);

   ctx.lineTo(x + flakeSize / 2, y + flakeSize / 2);
ctx.lineTo(x, y + flakeSize);
   ctx.lineTo(x - flakeSize / 2, y + flakeSize / 2);

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

ctx.fill();
}
```